# my error 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.'

Tags: vb.net, datareader

please help me for my homework. I can't finish because of this error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

This is my code:

```
    con.Open()

    Dim rs As New MySqlCommand("select * from account where username='" & txtu.Text & "' and password='" & txtp.Text & "' ", con)
    Dim sqlRead As MySqlDataReader = rs.ExecuteReader

    If sqlRead.HasRows Then
        If sqlRead.Read = True Then
            If sqlRead("level") = "admin" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Can't Delete.")

            ElseIf sqlRead("level") = "staff" Then
                Dim query As String = "delete from account where username='" & txtu.Text & "'"
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                sqlRead.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
con.Close()
```

Comment: what is not clear in that error message? An IDbConnection cannot serve other commands while serving a IDbDataReader. You need to close it before executing the command. Just move that close three lines up.

Comment: same error as well i move the close..

Comment: You need to set breakpoints and debug your code, only then you will know what code/line is causing the problem. Also IMO you need to look into [Using Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) to properly dispose objects that implement IDisposable as well as using parameters for your queries...

Comment: thank you for your help i got it..

Comment: Try to use parameters to avoid SQL injection. Beside this: before executing a NonQuery, you need to close your reader first.

Comment: In your `sqlconnection` string try adding in `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` ath the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

To do it the way youre trying you would need to also create a new connection for use with the new command, in which case youre going to causing avoidable connections.

```
    Private Sub DReader()
    Using Con As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("ConnectionString")
        Con.Open()
        Using MySqlReader As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader =
                New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("Command", Con).ExecuteReader
            While MySqlReader.Read
                Select Case MySqlReader.GetString(MySqlReader.GetOrdinal("level")).ToUpper
                    Case "ADMIN"
                        MessageBox.Show("Can't Delete.")
                    Case "STAFF"
                        Dim query As String = "delete from account where username='" & txtu.Text & "'"
                        DelRow(query)
                End Select
            End While
        End Using
        Con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub DelRow(ByVal Qry As String)
    Using Con As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("ConnectionString")
        Con.Open()
        Using DelCmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(Qry, Con)
            DelCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        Con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

I believe this answers your question, however, you should really be asking how to achieve the goal in which this routine is performing. Parameters and "ExecuteScalar" would be a better practice

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to place this code:
    sqlRead.Close()
after the last end if, since there will be a big chance to run the code when this " internal if " code is correct:
            If sqlRead("level") = "admin" Then
which needs to be closed as well.

In short, your reader will be closed ONLY if this code is executed:
                ElseIf sqlRead("level") = "staff" Then

So, update it to this:

```
If sqlRead.HasRows Then
    If sqlRead.Read = True Then
        If sqlRead("level") = "admin" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Can't Delete.")
        ElseIf sqlRead("level") = "staff" Then
            Dim query As String = "delete from account where username='" & txtu.Text & "'"
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    End If
End If
End If
sqlRead.Close()
con.Close()
```

I hope this helps you all,